# Thinkfan on Thinkpad T410 - thinkpad_acpi doesn't seem to support fan_control

Tags: thinkpad, fan, acpi

I try to run thinkfan.
I installed it and configured it.
But if i do this i get an error.

```
chris@chris-ThinkPad-T410:~$ sudo thinkfan -n

WARNING: Using default temperature inputs in /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal.
Config as read from /etc/thinkfan.conf:
Fan level   Low High
 0      0   42
 1      40  47
 2      45  52
 3      50  57
 4      55  62
 5      60  67
 6      65  72
 7      70  77
 127        75  32767
Module thinkpad_acpi doesn't seem to support fan_control
```

How to solve this?

Comment: for people landing here: enable fan_control via modprobe config file https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/thinkfan/+bug/787031/comments/2

Answer (score 3):

I was using the instructions here: http://x220.mcdonnelltech.com/ubuntu/ and was thus missing the driver option `expermental=1` in my `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf` file - which seems to be needed to get this working as expected.

Do the following:

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf
```

There should be a line

```
options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1
```

change it to

```
options thinkpad_acpi experimental=1 fan_control=1
```

Reboot your computer so the changes take effect.

Comment: Worked great! No need to reboot though, `sudo rmmod thinkpad_acpi ; sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi`was sufficient.

Comment: there is an issue thread here https://github.com/vmatare/thinkfan/issues/45

Answer (score 3):

first be sure the fan is enabled, as a default, its not :

```
echo "options thinkpad_acpi experimental=1 fan_control=1" >/etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf
```

relaunch the module :

```
sudo rmmod thinkpad_acpi ; sudo modprobe thinkpad_acpi
```

then edit the thinkfan config file

```
vi /etc/thinkfan.conf
```

mine is setup like that :

```
 tp_fan /proc/acpi/ibm/fan 

 tp_thermal /proc/acpi/ibm/thermal (0, 10, 15, 2, 10, 5, 0, 3, 0, 3)
 
 (0,    0,  41)
 (1,    40, 51)
 (2,    50, 56)
 (3,    55, 61)
 (4,    60, 65)
 (5,    64, 68)
 (7,    67, 32767)
```

the numbers are the temperature levels, for example > (5,   64, 68) means fan level 5 between 64 and 68 degrees

level 7, the maximum, above 67 degrees

```
service thinkfan restart
```

and check the messages with :

`journalctl -f`

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but you might want to have a look at http://www.thinkwiki.org/wiki/Fan_control_scripts. That place is always an excellent source for Thinkpad problems.

Comment: Those informations are outdated, i have Ubuntu 14.04 and i have no file `/etc/modprobe.d/thinkfan.conf`. I'm stuck at that step.